# Use sed to replace multiple and similar pattern

Tags: sed, design-patterns, similarity

I have two arrays of patterns, say orig[*] and repl[*], which I want to replace each orig[$i] in some tex files with corresponding repl[$i].

Although the patterns contain special characters (I somehow managed it), the original patterns, orig[*] are very similar, mostly different at the ending. e.g.

```
orig[1]=string   repl[1]=bla

orig[2]=string1   repl[2]=newbla

orig[3]=string2   repl[3]=else

orig[4]=string11   repl[4]=somethingelse

orig[5]=string$   repl[5]=jimbo
```

and so on.

I tried this code

```
sed -i -e 's/$orig[$i]/$repl[$i]/g' $filename
```

but it replaces all the above examples with 'string' and the rest is appended to them. I need to capture the EXACT `$orig[$i]` everytime.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think one sed program can loop over the bash arrays for you. We could build a bash script that uses sed, but we can get there with just bash:

```
cat > file << END
this is a string with string11 and string$ here
I also have string1 and string2 as well
END

orig=(string string1 string2 string11 string$)
repl=(bla newbla else somethingelse jimbo)

while IFS= read -r line; do
    for idx in "${!orig[@]}"; do 
        line=${line//${orig[idx]}/${repl[idx]}}
    done
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

```
this is a bla with bla11 and bla$ here
I also have bla1 and bla2 as well
```

Woops, the shorter "string" matched first. Let's rearrange the arrays so the longer patterns come first

```
orig=(string11 string1 string2 string$ string)
repl=(somethingelse newbla else jimbo bla)

while IFS= read -r line; do
    for idx in "${!orig[@]}"; do 
        line=${line//${orig[idx]}/${repl[idx]}}
    done
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

```
this is a bla with somethingelse and jimbo here
I also have newbla and else as well
```

There are programmatic ways to sort arrays by length, but I'll leave that as either as exercise or another question.

Comment: Thanks Glenn.I tried it with longest first, and it actually helped. Also, since I already knew all the endings were special characters (non-letter), I did it as:    sed -i -e 's/$orig[$i][^a..zA..Z]/$repl[$i]/g' $filename   I hope there is a more sophisticated way

Comment: `[^a..zA..Z]`is not what you want (it is identical to `[^aAzZ.]`). Use `a-z` for a range. Here you're looking for a non-alphabetic char, so use `[^[:alpha:]]`